# Visual Studio Project Not Running properly

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

When I open any application or start a new application it will build the application but it will not run the application. I have restarted my computer and checked task manager for any processes pertaining to my application. If I run visual studio as administrator the application will run but it will not build automatically even though in the visual studio setting it is set to build and run. However if I copy my application to another computer it builds and runs perfectly fine. I usually use Visual Studio 2010 Professional but I also have Visual Studio 2012. The problem is constant between the two applications. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you talking about executing tests or executing an actual application? Is that win app, console app??

Comment: Try resetting your settings to default. You can back up your current ones prior to doing so. Or you could copy the settings from 10 and put them in 12.

Comment: Executing the application. It is a win app. I just tried a console app and it did run but instantly sent a message saying "ConsoleApplication1" has stopped working. If I went to the directory of the console application and double clicked the EXE it created it worked fine. Also just tried resetting my settings with no luck.

Comment: @CloseVoters: in what way is this off-topic?  According to the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), questions are allowed to cover software tools commonly used by programmers.  I would consider Visual Studio to be such a tool.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the obj files withing your project directory.

Comment: Tried doing on a few different projects with no luck. Like I said it happens with a brand new project.